# Symfony2: How to getObjects linked to entity filtered by property on Object

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I normally try to search thoroughly before asking a question, but in this case I have no idea how to look up what I'm trying to do.

I have two Entities: Category and Ebooks linked in a ManyToMany relationship. Ebooks has a boolean property "active". I can get all Ebooks linked to a category by calling `$category->getEbooks();`, but I would like to know if it is possible to get only active Ebooks linked to the category without doing a whole query. Something like `$category->getEbooks(array('active' => true));`

I know I can do
`$this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('PmbLicensingBundle:Ebook')->
findBy(array('category' => $data['category_id'], active => true));` 
(although I'm not even sure if this would work, as my property on my ebook entity is categorIES (seeing as it's many to many)), but I was wondering if there is a way to do this from the category's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It seems that I should try my "intuitive" ideas before asking questions. `category->getEbooks(array('active' = true));` actually works perfectly.